# Sum with multiple Sum ranges for criteria in multiple criteria ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to sum using more than one sum range for a criteria matching in more than on criteria range.

Sample:
[image: Sample of the Situation]

I have tried searching solution to me problem but couldn't find.

I am not sure how should I be asking related question here, I am just attaching an image just i did earlier.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQBXW.png)

Comment: try sumifs() - that should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUMIFS requires that the ranges be the same size so you can do:

```
=SUMIFS(B:D,A:C,G2)
```

Or you can add two SUMIFS together:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,G2)+SUMIFS(D:D,C:C,G2)
```

Comment: thanks Scott, this works great, however I have one more criteria added to the situation and this criteria refers to single column, any workaround would be a help.

Comment: That is a new question and deserves its own post.

Comment: this works differently, I should be learning how to use this forum first.. Thanks Scott :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to achieve solution to the situation,

solution: 
          =SUM(IF(A1:C6=H2,IF(E1:E6=H3,B1:D6)))

Regards..